# How to access data from another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

My function is accepting workbook as an input. But I am not able to iterate the values in the workbook.
I am getting the error as the 'Object variable not set'.
P.S: I cannot use Range since the range is unknown.

```
Sub Test (wb as workbook)
Dim sheet as worksheet
Dim value as Integer
sheet = wb.worksheet(1)
value = sheet.Cells(1,1).Formula
return value
End sub
```

Comment: `Set sheet = wb.Worksheets(1)`....

Comment: There's no `Return` in VBA.

Comment: Why are you reading in the cell's `.Formula` instead of its `.Value`?

Comment: You can also construct a string that represents a range... `Range("A" & 1)` - but the use of `Cells` has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Actually this code has several more issues than a typo (@ close voters), therefore I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. The error you get is because you declared `Dim sheet As Worksheet` and `Worksheet` is an object and objects need to be `Set` like

   ```
   Set sheet = wb.worksheet(1)
   ```
2. You defined the variable `value` as `Integer` and then you try to read the `.Formula` into it which is a `String`. An `Integer` cannot hold a formula. I think you wanted to read the `.Cells(1,1).Value` instead.
3. VBA does not have a `return` you need to set your function `Test = value`
4. You used a procedure `Sub` and not a function therefore it cannot return any values. You need to change it into a `Function`

I think you should end up with something like that:

```
Public Function ReadMyValue(ByVal wb As Workbook) As Double 'or Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheet(1) 'use set for objects!

    Dim Value As Double 'or Long !!! but the same as your function is declared !!!
    Value = ws.Cells(1, 1).Value

    ReadMyValue = Value 'return the value to your function
End Function
```

And you can test it like:

```
Public Sub TestMyFunction()
    Debug.Print ReadMyValue(ThisWorkbook) 'will output the value of A1 of the first worksheet in this workbook.
End Sub
```